# How to delete all items from list?

Tags: sharepoint

How can I delete all items from a list in Sharepoint?

I have to delete my list and create it again... Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you have list with more than 500 items, and you don't want to chose coding path, and don't want to delete list as well, than you go to "Manage Content and Structure" view, it allows you to view 1000 items at once and than select all delete all.

Comment: thanks man! it works!! this is the easiest way to delete all items!

Comment: It allows you to view 1000 items, but it's impossible to delete all of them at the same time. Sharepoint allows you to delete only 100 items once. I don't understand why it marks answer here. @Thiago did it really work for you?

Comment: @anhtv13 Unfortunately, sometimes answers are marked or upvoted even without testing. Not everyone who upvotes actually tests the solution. :(

Comment: @anhtv13, on SharePoint Online  or O365, this works and I'm able to delete 1000 items at a time.

Comment: I can confirm it works in O365 / SharePoint Online as well

Comment: This works for me, the path is: **Site Settings / Site Content and Structure**

Answer (score 3):

You can connect Microsoft Access to SharePoint and run SQL commands to delete all records or use WHERE conditions. More Information at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/import-from-or-link-data-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA102749600.aspx.

Comment: the link is no longer valid, please explain how to connect

Answer (score 3):

You can delete all items at once in a Datasheet view (Ctrl+A > right click on the row > delete row).

Answer (score 2):

Go to Site Setting then look for Content and Structure click on then then look for your list once opened on the right corner select 1000 in show items, now you can easily delete 1000 items at a time. As SharePoint does not allow to delete more than 100 from direct list view.

Site Setting => Content and Structure => Select your List => select show 1000 => Delete

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [@Lukas Nespor](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/221151) to that work, you just have to install and import the right module.

Here is the code:

```
# Import the module from Sharepoint Online
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

$cc = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("Your website")
$cc.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("Your Email", (ConvertTo-SecureString "Your Password" -AsPlainText -Force))

$list = $cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your list name")
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>200</RowLimit></View>"

do
{
    $started = Get-Date
    $items = $list.GetItems($query)
    $cc.Load($items)
    $cc.ExecuteQuery()

    if ($items.Count -eq 0) { break }

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $items.Count; $i++)
    {
        # Delete row 
        # Because DeleteObject() effectively change the collection the index 0 is not a mistake
        $items[0].DeleteObject()
    }

    $cc.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Time elapsed: $((Get-Date) - $started)"
} while ($true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the suggestions before and if you have access to Power Automate you can create a flow which deletes all items of your list.

Your flow will look something like this:
[image: MS Flow: Delete all items of a SP list]

1. There is a manual trigger
2. Get all items of your SP list
3. Set the variable COUNT_OF_LIST to the length(outputs('Get_items_Items_of_list')?['body/value']) => The count of items in the list
4. Do until COUNT_OF_LIST is equal to 0
   [image]
5. Get all items you want to delete of your list
6. Apply to each of these items and delete it with the Delete Item action
7. Get all items of the list again
8. Set COUNT_OF_LIST to length(outputs('Get_items_Inner')?['body/value']) => The count of still leftover items

Since a normal Get Items action will only give you 100 items you need to set the Top Count in the advanced options to 4999 ([https://alextofan.com/2019/08/22/how-to-get-more-than-5000-item-from-sharepoint-online-in-flow/#:~:text=5000%20items%20limit&text=The%20maximum%20top%20count%20you,than%20100%20items%20are%20retrieved.](https://alextofan.com/2019/08/22/how-to-get-more-than-5000-item-from-sharepoint-online-in-flow/#:%7E:text=5000%20items%20limit&text=The%20maximum%20top%20count%20you,than%20100%20items%20are%20retrieved.))

This flow can be optimized, as it has a lot of Get Items actions. But for now this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In your SharePoint site you can go to your list and You can click on the checkbox beside the first item on the list (It should highlight all of the items) and then click on "Items" in the List Tools ribbon and you will see a delete button.

If you don't see the checkboxes edit the view by clicking on "List" in the Tools Ribbon and then go to modify view. Scroll to the bottom of the settings and you shoud see "Tabular View " and enable checkboxes.

That should help. :)

Comment: but my list has about 3000 items... i cant select all by clicking on the checkbox

Comment: There should be a box in the top left corner of your list that should highlight all of the items.

Comment: @Du6e that only seems to select all visible (page) items; not all items in the list/view.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online only, you can use Microsoft Graph and send in requests for each item on the list, deleting each item one by one (but quickly in a foreach loop).

1. Get the items from the list (method = GET):

/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items

2. Loop through each item and delete them (method = DELETE):

/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}

I do this with success as of today! Using my PowerShell module for MS Graph functions, https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSGraphAppOnlyEssentials

I get an Access Token using New-MSGraphAccessToken, then I use New-MSGraphQuery (which in a future version of the module will be renamed as 'New-MSGraphRequest').  You need to first setup an App Registration in Azure AD, and make sure it has the API permissions under Microsoft Graph API for Sites.ReadWrite.All.  Then you need to generate a self-signed certificate and store this in CurrentUser/My, and export/upload/import the cert (no private key necessary) into the App Registration in Azure AD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I would also be weary of the throttling limits, and considering putting a Start-Sleep in your foreach loop to avoid getting throttled.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete multiple items just by selecting items and delete key.

List ==>View Format ==> Quick Edit

Answer (score 0):

One option, if the list has a lot of elements, is to export the list as a template, delete the original list and recreate it from the template. (Or more generally, delete and re-create, but with the template, the latter step is less painful.)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete more than 100 items in a view by scrolling the list view - when you reach the end of the first 100 items an additional 100 items are loaded. I've been able to delete 2500 rows in this manner. It is not as fast as some of the previous answers, but it is possible.

[image: 2500 items selected in a sharepoint list]

[image: Delete operation...]

Another way - an easier way - to select large numbers of items in a list is to change the default number of items that display in the list.

1. Navigate to your list
2. Click the "All Items" option to display a list of options
3. Select "Edit Current View"
4. Look for "Number of items to display"
5. Enter the desired value (better not to exceed 500/600-ish)
6. Click "OK"
7. The list view will load
8. Select all items in the list and delete

Strangley setting the view to 1k of rows started producing delete issues for me - perhaps I'm causing an issue on the server during my back-to-back testing, that perhaps a queue of deletes has been created that is causing timeouts for the last items in the queue - thats a guess. Looking at the requests sent I see that things are "batched", so maybe this is the case.... point is that by modifying the list view to show more than the default number of rows, and/or by scrolling and causing more rows to load, you can select and delete large numbers of rows.